# How can I save my token after closing the browser so that I stay logged in?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, react-hooks, react-router

I have a React application that allows users to login using either google auth or email and password. In both cases, a JWT token containing the user ID is created. As long as the user has the respective browser open, he can reload the page without having to log in again. However, if the user closes the window, he must log in again because the token is no longer available. How can I change this ?

This is my auth controller class inside my server:

```
export const googleAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if (user) {
  console.log(user);
  const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT);
  res
    .cookie("access_token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
    })
    .status(200)
    .json(user._doc);
} else {
  console.log(req.body);
  const newUser = new User({
    ...req.body,
    fromGoogle: true,
  });
  const savedUser = await newUser.save();
  const token = jwt.sign({ id: savedUser._id }, process.env.JWT);
  res
    .cookie("access_token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
    })
    .status(200)
    .json(savedUser._doc);
 }
  } catch (err) {
 next(err);
 }
};
```

This is my verifyToken.js class, which checks whether the user is still logged in or whether the token is still available

```
export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
const token = req.cookies.access_token;

 if (!token) return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"));

 jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT, (err, user) => {
 if (err) return next(createError(403, "Token is not valid!"));
  req.user = user;
  next();
 });
};
```

And that is calling a route, which first checks the verifiyToken and then, if it exists, executes the method

```
import { verifyToken } from "../verifyToken.js";
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/fav", verifyToken, fav);



const loadArticel = async () => {
setLoading(true);
await axiosInstance
  .get(`/articel/fav`, { withCredentials: true })
  .then((res) => {
    setArticel(res.data);
    setLoading(false);
  });
 };
```

However, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Cookie vanishes when browser is closed. To persist data after closing the browser, you can save the data in the local storage instead of cookie. This way, token doesn't vanish and you don't have to login again.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the cookie an expiry date, for example 24 hours from now, it will not be deleted when the browser is closed.

```js
res.cookie("access_token", token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
});
```

But as a user, I would object to such a non-session cookie, unless I have checked an option "Keep me logged in for 24 hours" (or so) on the logon page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So you would, after closing the browser, expect to log in again?!

Comment: If I have checked the option, I expect a 24 h cookie, so that I remain logged in even after closing/reopening the browser.

Comment: Yes, or just "stay logged in". In any case, I'll install it, I've forgotten that by then. Thanks for the hint. And regarding my question, I will consider your answer!